# Identity proof of determinant of a Matrix

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm given the following exercise: let $a_{ij}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be $\mathcal{C}^1$ functions and $A(t):=(a_{ij}(t))$ the matrix whose entries are the $a_{ij}$ functions. Suppose that $\det A>0$ for every $t$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and call $B=(b_{ij})$ the inverse matrix of $A$. Show it holds the following:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\ln\det A=\sum_{i,j=1}^n\frac{da_{ij}}{dt}b_{ji}$$
I'm not sure how to tackle this. So far I reasoned that: $\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}b_{ji}=1$ implies $\sum_{i,j=1}^na_{ij}b_{ji}=n$ and thus $\sum_{i,j=1}^n\frac{db_{ij}}{dt}a_{ji}=-\sum_{i,j=1}^n\frac{da_{ij}}{dt}b_{ji}$ by derivation, but it didn't help me that much. Is it helpful to write $B$ as the matrix of algebraic complements of $A$? What is the idea to be followed?

Comment: You can use [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula).  Note that the right hand side is $\operatorname{tr}(A'B)=\operatorname{tr}(A' (\det(A)^{-1}\operatorname{adj}(A)))=\det(A)^{-1}\operatorname{tr}(A'\operatorname{adj}(A))$. Using Jacobi's formula you get that this is $\det(A)^{-1}\frac{d}{dt}\det(A)=\frac{d}{dt}\ln(\det(A))$.